# How to update MySQL Row at a later time?

Tags: python, mysql

**LANGUAGES USED:**

- Python
- Python Web Browsing with Mechanize
- Python HTML Parsing with BS4
- MySQL (later)

**OVERVIEW:**

I want to be able to track when a user logs on and logs off of a game server.

Like

ID, username, activty, loggedin, loggedoff

example:

1,archer,online,11-24-2015 05:10:11,11-24-2015 12:10:11

Using this data I want to then make a website that shows a chart of the most common times a particular player is online, the best time to play (when the most players are online) etc.

The ONLY data I am using to figure all this out is a "Who's Online" list published on the game's website.

So what I've done is I've written a python script that checks the list every 1minute (filters out all the HTML with BS4 and dumps to a text file of users online 1 per line), and it is able to figure out who signed on and who signed off by comparing to the list of the previous minute.

Now for the problem I am trying to figure out:

**THE PROBLEM:**

Currently the script just dumps the newly-online or newly-offline users to a text file.

I need to update a MySQL database like I said above instead.

I can google around and figure out how to get python to update the database everytime some comes online - just create a new row, auto increment the ID, put in the username, and a timestamp for when they signed on.

BUT I have no idea how I would be able to later, go and update that row to add the Logged Off time. How would I know what row to update?

There will be multiple rows with the same username, because a new row will be added for each logon/logoff session ! I know it will probably have to be found by the ID but how would I keep track of that?

Thanks!!!!!

**What I have:**

```
 # IMPORT WEB BROWSER
import mechanize

# IMPORT HTML PARSER
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString, Tag

# FOR TIME CALCS
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date

# FOR RENAMING FILES
import os

# FOR SLEEP
import time

# FOR TIMESTAMPS
import datetime

# Used for timestamps when writing to database [DB not used yet]
ts = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

###############################################################
# BEGIN NEVER ENDING LOOP THAT SLEEPS 1 MINUTE BETWEEN CYCLES #
###############################################################
# This will eventually be removed and will run as a 1min cronjob when ready

while True:


    #########################################
    # SETUP MECAHNIZE TO USE AS WEB BROWSER #
    #########################################

    br = mechanize.Browser()
    br.set_handle_equiv(True)
    br.set_handle_redirect(True)
    br.set_handle_referer(True)
    br.set_handle_robots(False)
    br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)

    ###########################################    
    # GET "WHO'S ONLINE?" LIST FROM GAME SITE #
    ###########################################

    try:
        # User-Agent
        br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; AS; rv:11.0) like Gecko')]
        r = br.open('http://en.war2.ru/wp-content/themes/war2.ru/lib/server-stats.php')
        page = r.read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
        user_list = soup.find_all('div', class_='status-list')
    except:
        print "ERROR: Connection failed. Retrying ..."
        continue

    #################################################
    # ERASE USERS ONLINE THIS MINUTE FROM LAST TIME #
    #################################################
    with open("users-on-this-minute.txt", "w") as f:
        f.close()

    #########################################################
    # FILTER OUT HTML AND GIVE A PLAIN LIST OF USERS ONLINE #
    #########################################################
    for br in user_list:
        users = br.findAll('br')

        for br in users:
            next = br.nextSibling
            if not (next and isinstance(next,NavigableString)):
                continue
            next2 = next.nextSibling
            if next2 and isinstance(next2,Tag) and next2.name == 'br':
                text = str(next.encode('latin1')).strip()
                if text:
                    output = next[1:].encode('latin1')

                    ####################################################
                    # PRINT EACH ONLINE USER TO TEXT FILE ONE PER LINE #
                    ####################################################
                    file = open("users-on-this-minute.txt", "at")
                    print >>file, str(output)
                    file.close

        ############################
        # CREATE NEWLY ONLINE LIST #
        ############################
        # Creates the Newly Online list by checking the users logged on now 
        # against the users logged on a minute ago. If there is a user logged on
        # now who wasn't on a minute ago, he is added to newly online

        with open("users-on-previous-minute.txt", "r") as f:
            check_online = f.readlines()
            new_online = set() # holds lines already seen
            outfile = open("users-newly-online.txt", "w")
            for line in open("users-on-this-minute.txt", "r"):
                if line not in check_online: # not a duplicate
                    new_online.add(line)
            outfile.writelines(sorted(new_online))
            outfile.close() 
            f.close()

        #############################
        # CREATE NEWLY OFFLINE LIST #
        #############################
        # Creates the Newly Offline list by checking the users logged on now 
        # against the users logged on a minute ago. If there was a
        # user logged on a minute ago but not now, he is added to newly offline

        with open("users-on-this-minute.txt", "r") as f:
            check_offline = f.readlines()
            new_offline = set() # holds lines already seen
            outfile = open("users-newly-offline.txt", "w")
            for line in open("users-on-previous-minute.txt", "r"):
                if line not in check_offline: # not a duplicate
                    new_offline.add(line)
            outfile.writelines(sorted(new_offline))
            outfile.close()      
            f.close()

        #############################################################
        # COPY CURRENT MINUTE LIST TO BECOME "PREVIOUS" MINUTE LIST #
        #############################################################
        # We are done using the list from the previous minute, and now we write
        # the current minute's list to become "previous minute" for next loop

        with open("users-on-this-minute.txt", "r") as f:
            lines = f.readlines()
            with open("users-on-previous-minute.txt", "w") as f1:
                f1.writelines(lines)
                f1.close()
            f.close()

        print "Sleeping for 1 minute ..."
        time.sleep(60)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are making this a bit too complicated.  The following is the gist of your question:

> BUT I have no idea how I would be able to later, go and update that row to add the Logged Off time. How would I know what row to update?
>
> There will be multiple rows with the same username, because a new row will be added for each logon/logoff session! I know it will probably have to be found by the ID but how would I keep track of that?

Since you have the username, all you have to do is update the row that doesn't have a log off time for that username.

```
"UPDATE logtable SET logouttime = NOW() WHERE username = " + username + " AND logouttime IS NULL"
```

When you set the database up the default value for `logouttime` will be `NULL`.

Comment: Thanks man!! So I would always INSERT for the loggedin part, then UPDATE when I get the loggedoff time, searching for username row with an empty loggedoff time. Is this correct? Also, would the loggedoff be "datetime" in MySQL table or just varchar

Comment: Glad to help.  Yes, on the login you would `INSERT` to create a new row and add the `username` and the `logintime`, then on logout, you would do an `UPDATE` to the `logouttime`.  The `NOW()` function inserts a `datetime` type.